# Реализация паттерна MVVM на WPF совместно с аудиовоспроизведением класса MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

ситуация такая: я решил создать своё wpf приложение - воспроизведение музыки, с изменением громкости, возможностью ставить звук на паузу, а так-же настраиваемым таймером отключения компьютера, но видимо замахнулся слишком высоко для своего уровня (развития), сначала создал форму, затем понял что намного легче будет сначала создать модель, но и здесь ничего не получается, я не понимаю даже самые простые вещи, в общем вот форма [image: View] а вот модель[image: model] я хотел бы понять как c помощью MediaPlayer и PropertyChanged создать обработку события изменения громкости, я понимаю что сильно туплю по этому можете мне посоветовать как мне быть чтобы сделать этот проект, может быть почитать какие либо книги и т.д

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` не привязывает, он оповещает, это эвент (событие). Он не является источником данных, так как вы хотите его связать с `MediaPlayer`?

Comment: Извините за непонимание, я имел ввиду как с помощью INotifyPropertyChanged изменить громкость, ведь как я понимаю класс MediaPlayer нужно реализовать и каким то образом создать и обработать событие

Comment: Смотрите... Есть интерфейс, он не знает нечего о работе вашего кода, вообще, он знаешь, что просто ему надо получить значение с указанного свойства. Теперь свойство, если сделать простое `public int SoundValue {get;set;}`, то при изменение значений в интерфейсе - свойство получит эти данные, но если изменить свойство из кода, то интерфейс не получит эти обновления. Тут на помощь приходит INPC, этот интерфейс реализует событие, которое принимает **не значение**, а **имя свойства** которое обновилось. То есть вы говорите интерфейсу "Ей, у меня свойство "SoundValue" изменило значение!".

Comment: Тут я думаю вы теперь поняли для чего INPC. Теперь идем дальше. Если у вас это свойство привязано успешно например к ползунку, то вы должны были увидеть все изменения. Тогда вопрос, в чем проблема, в чем затруднения, при чем тут INPC?